# How to highlight multiple intersecting areas under multiple curves at the same time?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here is my code, as you see there is a significant flaw where the blue area is popping out and covering other regions.

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=2:8, samples=500, width=20cm]
        \addplot [no marks, fill=red, opacity=.2, draw=none, stack plots=y] {min(gauss(4,.5),gauss(6,.5)) } \closedcycle;
        \addplot [no marks, fill=blue, opacity=.2, draw=none, stack plots=y] {min(gauss(4,.5),gauss(4.5,.5)) } \closedcycle;
        \addplot [solid] {gauss(4,.5)} node[above, pos=.25, rotate=75] {};
        \addplot [solid] {gauss(4.5,.5)};
        \addplot [solid] {gauss(6,.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is a (clipped) screenshot of the current result:

[image: image showing a screenshot of the current result]

Comment: I guess you have to remove the `stack plots=y`'s to get the desired result.

Comment: Wow you are right. Btw, any idea on how to hlighlihght the area by using lines or some pattern instead of filled colours?

Comment: Got the patterns on my own. Now if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it so that you get some Internet points. Thank you very much for your promt response.

Comment: Sure, replace the `fill` with e.g. `pattern=north west lines`. But to use it you have to load the corresponding library.

Comment: You are such an Internet meme God.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is (with some comments) ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}   % <-- needed to use `pattern's as you guess
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.12,    % <-- to use Lua when using LuaLaTeX (which is faster)
    }
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=2:8,
        samples=101,            % <-- reduced value to compile faster
%        width=20cm,            % <-- commented to see the lines better
        smooth,
    ]
        \addplot [
            no marks,
            fill=red,
            opacity=.2,
            draw=none,
%            stack plots=y,     % <-- that were causing the mess
        ] {min(gauss(4,.5),gauss(6,.5))}
            \closedcycle
        ;
        \addplot [
            no marks,
            % use `pattern' instead of `fill'
%            fill=blue,
            pattern=north west lines,
            opacity=.2,
            draw=none,
%            stack plots=y,
        ] {min(gauss(4,.5),gauss(4.5,.5))}
            \closedcycle
        ;
        \addplot [solid] {gauss(4,.5)}
            node [above, pos=.25, rotate=75] {};    % <-- what is is good for?
        \addplot [solid] {gauss(4.5,.5)};
        \addplot [solid] {gauss(6,.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Totally unrelated, but how do you stackexchangers paste LaTeX previews?

Comment: There is an "image" button in the toolbar of the question/answer box.

Comment: Do you save the preview locally, then upload the image?

Comment: I don't use Overleaf or ShareLaTeX so I just make a screenshot of the previewed PDF and upload it.